# List Index Out of Range for Bellman Ford Algorithm Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bellman-ford

I am trying to create a Bellman-Ford algorithm in Python3 and I keep getting the error "list index out of range."

For an array with 3 inputs, ex:

```
graph = 
[[1, 2, 1.5],
 [1, 3, 1.0],
 [2, 1, 1.5],
 [2, 6, 1.25]]
```

I am trying to iterate over the number of nodes and links:

```
for i in range(nodes-1): 
    for j in range(links-1): 
        if dist[graph[j][0]] + graph[j][2] < dist[graph[j][1]]: 
            dist[graph[j][1]] = dist[graph[j][0]] + graph[j][2]
```

I have checked that:

- graph[0] pulls back the first (zeroth) row of the graph array
- graph[max # of links included -1] pulls back the last row of the array
- range(nodes-1) is correct
- range(links-1) is correct

What could be causing this?

```
graph = [[1, 2, 1.5], [1, 3, 1.0], [2, 1, 1.5], [2, 6, 1.25]] 
nodes = 6 
links = 4 
source = 0 
def BellmanFord(graph, nodes, links, source): 
    dist = [9_000_000] * nodes dist[source] = 0 
    for i in range(nodes-1): 
        for j in range(links): 
            if dist[graph[j][0]] + graph[j][2] < dist[graph[j][1]]: 
                dist[graph[j][1]] = dist[graph[j][0]] + graph[j][2] 
BellmanFord(graph,nodes,links,source)
```

Comment: Can you please explain your input ? What are the nodes, edges and weights ?

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In this example, nodes=6 total nodes in graph, edges/links=4 total edges in graph. in graph[ ] the inputs are graph[startNode,endNode,weight].

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Something which can *literally* be copy/pasted into a python interpreter and reproduces the issue you've described in the question (i.e., throws an `IndexError`)

Comment: Ahh, okay. Here is the code:
graph = [[1, 2, 1.5],
 [1, 3, 1.0],
 [2, 1, 1.5],
 [2, 6, 1.25]]
nodes = 6
links = 4
source = 0
def BellmanFord(graph, nodes, links, source): 
  
    dist = [9_000_000] * nodes
    
    dist[source] = 0
  
    for i in range(nodes-1): 
        for j in range(links): 
            if dist[graph[j][0]] + graph[j][2] < dist[graph[j][1]]: 
                dist[graph[j][1]] = dist[graph[j][0]] + graph[j][2]
BellmanFord(graph,nodes,links,source)

Comment: The code given in the comment differs from that in the posted question, in that the comment code contains `for j in range(links)` rather than `range(links-1)`. When I run the code given in the question, I don't get an `IndexError`

Comment: you are getting error in `dist[graph[j][1]]` because when `j` reaches `3` value returned by `graph[3][1]` is `6` and `dist[6]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you @N.Moudgil! I just needed to change my nodes from n=6 to n=7 (because the nodes range is 0 to n-1)! THANK YOU!!!!